# Salvando dados PHP e HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql

Seguinte, estou com um formulário aqui ao preencher ele uso o PHP para validar os dados e salvar no banco de dados MySql. No entanto, digito a data normal e ao visualizar a tabela dos dados salvos, a data é o único q fica sem ser armazenado. Alguém poderia dar um HELP. thanks!

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
    $msgErro = "";

  $nomeMarca = $modelo = $mei = $operadora = $datafabricao = "";

  $nomeMarca          = filtraEntrada($_POST["nomeMarca"]);     
  $modelo             = filtraEntrada($_POST["modelo"]);
  $mei                = filtraEntrada($_POST["mei"]);
  $operadora          = filtraEntrada($_POST["operadora"]);
  $datafabricao       = filtraEntrada($_POST["datafabri"]);

  try
    {    
    // Função definida no arquivo conexaoMysql.php
    $conexao = conectando();

    $sql = "
      INSERT INTO Celular (DataFabricacao, MEI, Modelo, NomeMarca, Operadora)
      VALUES ('$datafabricao', $mei, '$modelo', '$nomeMarca', '$operadora');
    ";

    if (! $conexao->query($sql))
      throw new Exception("Erro na inserção de dados: " . $conexao->error);

    $formProcSucesso = true;
  }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $msgErro = $e->getMessage();
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <title>Exercício 02</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Cadastro Celular</h2>
  <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]); ?>" method="POST">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="nomeMarca">Nome Marca:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Informe a marca do Celular" name="nomeMarca" id="nomeMarca" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">Modelo:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Informe o modelo do Celular" name="modelo" id="modelo" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="">MEI:</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Informe o MEI" name="mei" id="mei" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="operadora">Operadora:</label>
      <select name="operadora" id="operadora" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="tim">TIM</option>
        <option value="vivo">VIVO</option>
        <option value="claro">CLARO</option>
        <option value="claro">ALGAR</option>
        <option value="claro">NEXTEL</option>
        <option value="claro">OI</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="datafabri">Data Fabricação:</label>
      <input type="date"  class="form-control" placeholder="Data Fabricação do Celular" name="datafabri" id="udatafabri" required>
    </div>   

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
  </form>
```

---

```
function filtraEntrada($dado) 
{
  $dado = trim($dado);
  $dado = stripslashes($dado);
  $dado = htmlspecialchars($dado);

  return $dado;
}
```

-

```
if ($arrayCelulares != "")
    {

      foreach ($arrayCelulares as $celular)
      {       
        echo "
        <tr>
          <td>$celular->nomeMarca</td>
          <td>$celular->modelo</td>
          <td>$celular->mei</td>
          <td>$celular->operadora</td>
          <td>$celular->datafabri</td>
          <td><a href= 'excluirCelular.php?MEI=$celular->mei'>Excluir celular</a> </td>     
        </tr>      
      }
    }
```

-

```
class Celular 
{
  public $nomeMarca;
  public $modelo;
  public $operadora;
  public $mei;
  public $dataFabri;
}

function getCelular($conexao)
{
  $arrayCelulares = [];

  $SQL = "
  SELECT * FROM Celular
  ";

  $resultado = $conexao->query($SQL);
  if (! $resultado)
    throw new Exception('Ocorreu uma falha ao gerar o relatorio de testes: ' . $conexao->error);

  if ($resultado->num_rows > 0)
  {
    while ($row = $resultado->fetch_assoc())
    {
      $celular = new celular();

      $celular->nomeMarca         = $row["NomeMarca"];
      $celular->modelo            = $row["Modelo"];
      $celular->mei               = $row["MEI"];
      $celular->operadora         = $row["Operadora"];
      $celular->dataFabri         = $row["DataFabricacao"];
      $arrayCelulares[] = $celular;
    }
  }
  return $arrayCelulares;
```

Comment: Estranho eu consegui inserir. A coluna `DataFabricacao` está em timestamp, date ou datetime?

Comment: date cara, ta foda! Ai foi ?

Comment: ta no formato YYYY-MM-DD?

Comment: sim @WeesSmith, consegui arrumar o seguinte problema de não inserção no banco, porém, agora eu criei uma tabela com php e html para por tais dados, e a data é a única a não aparecer. Tem alguma ideia porque?

Comment: Dê um `echo $sql;` e veja a instrução final. Se tiver trazendo tudo ok, tente executar direto no MySql, assim você vê o erro. E caso não tiver trazendo corretamente, você consegue ver e identificar onde pode ser (post/get, aspas, formato, etc )

Comment: @RBZ não fez sentido aqui o erro que apontou, sendo que o erro é se conectar com o banco..

Comment: @Gabriel eu não vejo erro na conexão se ele disse isso "...ao visualizar a tabela dos dados salvos, a data é o único q fica sem ser armazenado..."

Comment: @RBZ a data ta armazenada no banco, o problema é, ao criar uma tabela com os dados do banco na tabela o único campo que não aparece é a data. Aí que está morando o problema.

Comment: Nossa que rolo ! Como você está definindo o `value` do `input` da data ?

Comment: está sem value amigo

Comment: Acho que você não está inserindo no formato que você definiu no banco

Comment: Posta onde você processa esses dados: `<td>$celular->datafabri</td>`. Ou melhor, posta esse retorno: `$arrayCelulares`. Esse seu `foreach` está estranho.

Comment: @RBZ feito. De uma olhada

Comment: @AndersonHenrique no banco ela está no formato US, como faço para por ele na tabela em tal formato então ?

Comment: @Gabriel dá um `print_r($arrayCelulares)`. Assim facilita saber se está trazendo o valor.

Comment: @RBZ pode deixar eu acredito que voces não estao entendo, bye and thanks!

Comment: @Gabriel Caso tenha resolvido seu problema, seria legal informar. Se estamos pedindo mais informações, é porque sua pergunta não trás detalhes suficientes para identificarmos. Os pedidos nos comentários servem exatamente para isso, solicitar mais informações. Mas se quer desistir, sem problemas, estaremos aqui caso queira uma mão.

Comment: @RBZ não resolvi, porém, se conseguir, atualizo sim com a resolução.

Comment: @Gabriel Faça o seguinte $data = new DateTime(str_replace("/", "-",$_POST['datafabri'])); $datafabricao       = filtraEntrada($data->format('Y-m-d')); Caso não funcionar faça oque o RMZ falou, poste o retorno do print_r

Comment: @Gabriel, então informe como as variáveis estão salvas e como vc esta trazendo elas

Comment: Consegui o que queria, no insert no lugar de 'datafabricao' coloquei NOW() e deu certo. Valeu a todos e desculpe !